# angularjs: ng-bind variable updated in karma unit test, but view not updated

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, karma-jasmine

html:

```
<div id="id" ng-bind="node.name" title="{{func(node.name)}}"></div>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.func = function _func(name) {
  let w = angular.element('#id').width();
  console.log(w);
  return w;
}
```

test.js

```
describe('test', () => {
  // prepare scope ...
  $scope.node.name = 'testtesttestname';
  let element = angular.element('#id');
  angular.element(document).find('body').append(element); // Line 5
  expect($scope.func('testtesttestname') > 0).to.be.true();
})
```

I am new to angularjs.

In the above html, there is a `div` with ng-bind. in `test.js`, I updated `$scope.node.name` with a new name. and `func()` is supposed to return the real width of `div` after updating. but without line 5, it seems that the `width` is always 0. why? any better way to replace `angular.element(document).find('body').append(element);`